# Average between neighbour positions

Tags: c

I have a square matrix and I need to do the average between the neighbours of each matrix position which has all their neighbours inside the matrix itself.

Explaining with an example, if I have a matrix like that:

```
10 11  1  4
 5  1  6  9
 9  0  2  7
 7  4  9  8
```

The average will be calculated only in the positions (2,2), (2,3), (3,2) and (3,3).

After those operations, the final matrix will be this listed bellow:

```
5.00  4.56
4.78  5.11
```

Sorry for my confused explanations, I'm a beginner at C language and I'm having a lot of difficulties to do this algorithm.

I will be grateful for everyone who can explain that to me and show me a solution.

Comment: Please explain further. I.e., how do you get 5 in top left corner?

Comment: This is an identical problem to applying a blur filter to an image. There is a lot of code available for that out there if you want to search for it.

Comment: If (3,2) i.e. 9 average could be computed, why not (1,3), (2,0) which has 9. Also why not other values like 6, 5, which have their neighbors. Could you please elaborate on your algorithm?

Comment: Ok.. I got the algorithm. It is a 3x3 window centered around 1, 6, 0, 2 . So 5 is essentially the mean of a 3x3 window around 1.

Comment: Aha, got it. Damon, the best way to get help is to show your best effort and explain what exactly you can't achieve. Otherwise your question will be ignored/downvoted/closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code you show I guess your problem is in the creation of the algorithm itself rather than C.

I would suggest to 1. have a function which averages numbers in a 3x3 matrix. 2. make a loop which goes through your matrix applying this function to appropriate chunks.

Each of these steps is not hard to accomplish and I'm sure you'll find lots of code online which will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** It is recommended that you show what you have tried or attempted so far. Usually, a generic open question without any prior attempt gets down-voted. Since, you are beginner and am a lover of image processing, I couldn't help writing this code and  posting this solution to help you get started.

As Paulpro commented, your problem is a low-pass filter implementation. In a given data matrix, you will have to find out the points which could be averaged through a 3 x 3 window. Hence, first I will explain how to identify these points. Please find a sample code with comments below which will explain the identification of these points.

```
// Input Data
int input_array[4][4] = { {10, 11, 1, 4}, {5, 1, 6, 9}, {9, 0, 2, 7}, {7, 4, 9, 8}};

// To calculate the average 
float sum ;

// Row counter, column counter, dimension of the square matrix
int row_ctr, col_ctr, array_dimension;
int row, col;

array_dimension = 4; // Initialization

// Run the loop for the entire array    
for(row_ctr = 0; row_ctr < array_dimension; row_ctr++)
{
    // If the current row's top neighbor is outside the boundary or
    // the bottom neighbor is outside the boundary, PASS and continue with
    // next row
    if(((row_ctr - 1) < 0) || ((row_ctr + 1) >= array_dimension))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Run the loop for array dimension
    for(col_ctr = 0; col_ctr < array_dimension; col_ctr++)
    {
         // If the current column's left neighbor is outside the boundary or
         // right neighbor is outside the boundary, PASS and continue with
         // next column
         if(((col_ctr - 1) < 0) || ((col_ctr + 1) >= array_dimension))
         {
              continue;
         }
         // Initialize sum to 0.0
         sum = 0.0;
         // Reset to Top Left corner by going (-1, -1) from current position
         row = row_ctr - 1; 
         col = col_ctr - 1;

         sum = input_array[(row+0)][col] + 
                 input_array[(row+0)][(col+1)]+ input_array[(row+0)][(col+2)];
         sum += input_array[(row+1)][col] + 
                  input_array[(row+1)][(col+1)]+ input_array[(row+1)][(col+2)];
         sum += input_array[(row+2)][col] + 
                  input_array[(row+2)][(col+1)]+ input_array[(row+2)][(col+2)];

         // Find the average    
         sum = sum / 9.0;
         printf("Average being found for (%d, %d) is %6.2f\n", row_ctr, col_ctr, sum);
     }
}
```

When this code is executed the output would be displayed as

```
Average being found for (1, 1) is   5.00
Average being found for (1, 2) is   4.56
Average being found for (2, 1) is   4.78
Average being found for (2, 2) is   5.11
```